# Installing CH341 Serial Driver on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, drivers, usb

I've got a USB3.0/HDMI adapter to connect my laptop to a second monitor. At first, just connecting the USB, it seems the Device is somehow "unknown" as per lsusb command bellow (same happens leveraging the usbview tool) - refer to the  1d5c: 2000.

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:07da Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 045e:07b2 Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 004: ID 1d5c:2000  
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 13d3:5170 IMC Networks 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Thing is though, even after downloading the driver (https://github.com/skyrocknroll/CH341SER_LINUX) that supports my kernel 4.15, installing as per directions. I can verify the module installed and loaded in the kernel `modinfo ch341`

However, what I also could note is that I get the following output from dmesg when I insert the usb:

```
 [Sun Apr 12 03:13:31 2020] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[Sun Apr 12 03:13:31 2020] usb 4-1: config 1 interface 1 altsetting 0 has a duplicate endpoint with address 0x81, skipping
[Sun Apr 12 03:13:31 2020] usb 4-1: config 1 interface 1 altsetting 0 has a duplicate endpoint with address 0x1, skipping
[Sun Apr 12 03:13:31 2020] usb 4-1: config 1 interface 1 altsetting 1 has a duplicate endpoint with address 0x81, skipping
[Sun Apr 12 03:13:31 2020] usb 4-1: config 1 interface 1 altsetting 1 has a duplicate endpoint with address 0x1, skipping
[Sun Apr 12 03:13:31 2020] usb 4-1: config 1 interface 1 altsetting 2 has a duplicate endpoint with address 0x81, skipping
[Sun Apr 12 03:13:31 2020] usb 4-1: config 1 interface 1 altsetting 2 has a duplicate endpoint with address 0x1, skipping
[Sun Apr 12 03:13:31 2020] usb 4-1: config 1 interface 1 altsetting 3 has a duplicate endpoint with address 0x81, skipping
[Sun Apr 12 03:13:31 2020] usb 4-1: config 1 interface 1 altsetting 3 has a duplicate endpoint with address 0x1, skipping
[Sun Apr 12 03:13:31 2020] usb 4-1: config 1 interface 1 altsetting 4 has a duplicate endpoint with address 0x81, skipping
[Sun Apr 12 03:13:31 2020] usb 4-1: config 1 interface 1 altsetting 4 has a duplicate endpoint with address 0x1, skipping
[Sun Apr 12 03:13:31 2020] usb 4-1: config 1 interface 1 altsetting 5 has a duplicate endpoint with address 0x81, skipping
[Sun Apr 12 03:13:31 2020] usb 4-1: config 1 interface 1 altsetting 5 has a duplicate endpoint with address 0x1, skipping
[Sun Apr 12 03:13:31 2020] usb 4-1: config 1 interface 1 altsetting 6 has a duplicate endpoint with address 0x81, skipping
[Sun Apr 12 03:13:31 2020] usb 4-1: config 1 interface 1 altsetting 6 has a duplicate endpoint with address 0x1, skipping
[Sun Apr 12 03:13:31 2020] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d5c, idProduct=2000
[Sun Apr 12 03:13:31 2020] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
```

Has anyone came across with a similar issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: CH341 is usually serial TTL-USB UART converter and sometimes programmer. Why do you think that it handles HDMI? How did Windows detect it?

Comment: @N0rbert That is a device (cheap-one) a bought from VCOM that is designed for converting HDMI to USB3.0. I haven't tried on Windows yet, working on it now.

Comment: @N0rbert on windows it works perfectly by installing the driver comes with the adapter. Driver is a developed by Fresco Logic https://drivers.softpedia.com/get/GRAPHICS-BOARD/OTHERS/Fresco-Logic-FL2000-USB-3-0-Display-Controller-Driver-2-1-33676-0.shtml